# Split bitmaps into multiple PDF pages

Tags: c#

I need to print a panel multiple times (1 to 24 times) into a PDF file. A page can fit about 4 panels.

The problem is, if I try to print it more than 4 times, the 5th bitmap will appear cut off at the bottom of the page instead of going to the next page. I also can't duplicate the pages as the panels have labels with different values.

I've tried condtitions with e.HasMorePages but still nothing.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylris.jpg)

Is there a way to split them in groups into different pages?

**Printing code**

```
private void imprimir_btn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument doc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
        doc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.Document = doc;

        if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            doc.Print();
        }

    }
```

**Bitmap Drawing**

```
 private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        int bnds = 55;
        int xcont = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= mensalidade_input.Value; i++)
        {
            contrato_lbl.Text = xcont.ToString() + "/" + mensalidade_input.Value;

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(doc_pnl.Width, doc_pnl.Height, doc_pnl.CreateGraphics());
            doc_pnl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, doc_pnl.Width, doc_pnl.Height));
            RectangleF bounds = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;
            float factor = ((float)bmp.Height / (float)bmp.Width);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, bounds.Left, bnds, bounds.Width, factor * bounds.Width);

            bnds = bnds + 265;
            xcont = xcont + 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make current index to global and sum printed image height if it greater than the print area height set **HasMorePages** to true it will add one more page again call the print page event,

```
int currentIndex = 1;
    private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        int bnds = 55;
        int xcont = 1;

        for (; currentIndex <= mensalidade_input.Value; currentIndex++)
        {
            contrato_lbl.Text = xcont.ToString() + "/" + mensalidade_input.Value;

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(doc_pnl.Width, doc_pnl.Height, doc_pnl.CreateGraphics());
            doc_pnl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, doc_pnl.Width, doc_pnl.Height));
            RectangleF bounds = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;
            filledHeight += bmp.Height;
            if (bounds.Height < filledHeight)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                return;
            }
            float factor = ((float)bmp.Height / (float)bmp.Width);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, bounds.Left, bnds, bounds.Width, factor * bounds.Width);

            bnds = bnds + 265;
            xcont = xcont + 1;
        }
        currentIndex = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. With a little tweaking it started working exactly as I intended to. Was able to adjust your code for it to print 4 bitmaps per page with the correct labels.